# Como usar caracteres reservados en VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy intentando obtener el valor del array "torznab:attr" dentro del objeto "items"

```
<img v-bind:src="items.torznab:attr[5].attr.value" />
```

y como es un carácter reservado me salta este error:

**[vue/no-parsing-error]
Parsing error: Unexpected token :.**

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes publicar el objecto `items`?

Comment: Es un objeto normal, lo que uno de ellos se llama ''torznab:attr" y al tener " : " vue lo trata con un caracter especial, mi pregunta es como puedo usarlo. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu `items` es como aquí:

```js
const items = {
  "torznab:attr": [{
      attr: {
        value: 'test 1'
      }
    }, {
      attr: {
        value: 'test 2'
      }
    }, {
      attr: {
        value: 'test 3'
      }
    },
    {
      attr: {
        value: 'test 4'
      }
    }, {
      attr: {
        value: 'test 5'
      }
    }, {
      attr: {
        value: 'test 6'
      }
    }
  ]
};

console.log(items["torznab:attr"][5].attr.value);
```

`<img v-bind:src="items['torznab:attr'][5].attr.value" />` es correcto.